# Cracking MD5, SHA1, SHA256 hashes

Tags: hash, md5

Hey guys i am trying to crack some hashes and it seems to be taking longer then expected (going on 7 days now). I am using John the ripper, I cant use hash cat due to pc limitations. I used online decrypters, it could decrypt some of the hashes but not all of them. I literally tried probably almost every online decrypter but some of the hashes wont crack.

Any suggestions on how I can crack them?

Comment: Why are you expecting it to take less than 7 days?

Comment: If the password is sufficiently strong you will not recover it in a billion years, even when it was hashed with unsalted single-iteration MD5.

Comment: Passwords are not encrypted. They are hashed. Hash functions are one way. The opposite of "encrypt" is "decrypt". There is no "opposite", in the same sense of the word, of a hash function.  All you can do with password hashes is to think of potential passwords, try hashing them, and check if the output matches. Or you can precompute the same thing and store a key-value database matching hash outputs to known inputs. It amounts to either guess-and-check or known answer lookup. There is nothing else to it. You can only optimize these techniques.

Comment: And the major consequence of that property is that although some passwords are really easy to crack, simply because password crackers try to start with passwords more likely to succeed, but not all passwords are equally easy to guess. (And all password cracking programs do is guess.) Some passwords will be hard or impossible to guess. And you can't tell if a hash is the hash of a weak password without brute force. Either you find out it's a weak password by guessing-and-checking weak passwords and succeeding. Or you find it's not weak by guessing every possible weak password and failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your options may include:

Search the internet for the hash

- Someone may have cracked it already

Use good word lists

- John the Ripper probably comes with some, but they also [sell more/better wordlists](http://www.openwall.com/wordlists/)

Try to answer the "security questions"

- If these are password hashes for some online service that you need access to, there may be "security questions", and the answers are often times easily guessed.
- There are [lists for these answers](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Miscellaneous/security-question-answers)
- May not (*hopefully does not*) let you recover the password, but would let you change it and log in to the service.

Learn the password generation algorithm

- Assuming the hash is of a password, it may not be a uniformly random password
- Learning the distribution of the outputs of the algorithm will help you to narrow the search space

Buy a bunch of GPUs

- Probably not an option, unless you are very well funded

Rent time on Amazon (or an equivalent service)<s>*</s>

- You can rent GPU time instead of buying GPUs

Hack the box

- Only applicable if this is for a CTF/penetration testing engagement/etc

  - Otherwise **this is illegal**
- The password or input to the hash function might be sitting in a file somewhere

### Note

It is entirely possible that at least some of the hashes you are trying to crack simply cannot be cracked by computational means. If the password is a 32 character long uniformly random string, then no amount of computing power will help you.